# jQuery Dialog issues in IE9

Tags: jquery, dialog, internet-explorer-9

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <link href="themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="includes/jquery.cluetip.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="includes/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.cluetip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.ui.mouse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.ui.draggable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.ui.resizable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery.ui.dialog.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="includes/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 

 function ClosePopUp() {
     $('#dialog').dialog('close');
     var NewModelNo = $('#hdnModelNumber').val();
     $("#ddlModelNumber option[value='" + NewModelNo + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
     $('#ddlModelNumber').change();
     return true;
 }


    $(function ()  { 
         var buttons = $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').children('button');
         buttons.remove();
         $('#dialog').append(' <br/>'); 
         $('#dialog').dialog({      
         title: '<span class="modalpopup-title">Model Renamed</span>',
         modal:false,
         height:250,
         width:560,
         position:'top',
         autoOpen:false
         });
         $("#ddlModelNumber").bind('change', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         ModelPopup();  
        });             
     });
    function ModelPopup() { 
             var ModelNo = $('#ddlModelNumber :selected').val();
             var NewModelNo = $('#hdnModelNumber').val();
             if (ModelNo == NewModelNo) {
                 return true;
             }
             jQuery.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                 data: "{ 'ModelNo': '" + ModelNo + "' }",
                 dataType: 'json',
                 url: 'product-registration.aspx/CheckConflicts',
                 success: function(result) {
                     if (jQuery.trim(result.d).length > 0) {
                         $('#dialog').text('');
                         var NewModelNo = result.d;
                         $('#hdnModelNumber').val(NewModelNo);
                         var content = "<span class='modalpopup-content'>The model " + ModelNo + " has been renamed to " + NewModelNo + " so " + NewModelNo + "<br/>"
                         content += "has been selected in the Model drop down menu.</span>";
                         $('#dialog').append(content); //message to display in divmessage div
                         $('#dialog').append('<br/> <br/><a><img src ="images/sp_int_closeWindow_btn.gif" alt ="Close" onclick="javascript:return ClosePopUp();" id="messagego" /></a>');
                         $("#dialog").attr("style", "font: 11px; font-family: Arial; font-weight: bold;visibility:visible;");
                         $('#dialog').dialog('open');
                         return false;
                     }
                 }
             });
             return true;
 }
```

This above code works fine in chrome but causing weird problems in IE. It is actually behaving inconsistent. To Summarize, when the page loads first time, on change of a dropdown pop up doesnt appear rather throws some errors in libraries(rarely) and if i refresh the page dialog appears. Please help!!!!

Comment: Please also add the html, so the script can be run.

Comment: <HTML> <HEAD>script pasted above is placed here</HEAD> <body text="#000000" bgColor="#5d7180" leftMargin="0" topMargin="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"> <center> <div id="dialog"></div> <form id="form1" method="post" runat="server"></form></body></HTML> Please help....

Comment: Why does the above code does not work in IE..? especially first time then after refresh it works...not able to predict why!